# I am getting an error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@heroicons/react/solid'

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, package.json, tailwind-ui, heroicons

I have run

```
npm install @heroicons/react
```

and my package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"@headlessui/react": "^1.6.6",
"@heroicons/react": "^2.0.0",
...
```

but for some reason I cannot get it to work!

I am still getting this error

Please help me out here. I don't understand what is the issue here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In version `2.0.0`, [according to the docs](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons#react), the icons should be imported from:

- `@heroicons/react/20/solid`
- `@heroicons/react/24/outline`
- `@heroicons/react/24/solid`

For example:

```js
import { AcademicCapIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { BeakerIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { PlayIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid';

function Preview() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AcademicCapIcon />
      <BeakerIcon />
      <PlayIcon />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this was exactly the issue I was facing. Next time I will make it a point to look inside the node_modules folder.